# backslashes lost when read as command-line arguments from process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments

In my node.js program I only accept one command line argument to my program which I am reading in like so:

`const path = process.argv[2]`

As the name implies, it expects a file path. On Unix systems it works fine since paths use forward slashes (`/`) but I want it to work on Windows as well, so for eg. if the user calls the program like so:

`node myExampleProgram.js C:\Users\Joe\blah.txt`

it can then convert those backslashes (`\`) to forward slashes (`/`). The problem is that the backslashes are already lost, so in the eg above the `path` variable would now contain the value: `C:UsersJoeblah.txt`. I guess it's interpreting the backslashes as escape characters and since `\U`, `\J` and `\b` aren't escape sequences it's simply deleting them? If that's the case then how can i get process.argv to interpret them as string literals (and ignore any backslashes)?

Note: The program *does* work if we pass the path value surrounded in quotes like so:

`node myExampleProgram.js 'C:\Users\Joe\blah.txt'`

But I would like to get it to work without this requirement

Comment: inside the root folder after the `cli function` works, you can use cmd  `npm link` as alias cmd for the cli. please refer to [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running my Node.JS script in Git Bash, and thus the slashes (back and forward) were being interpreted in the manner of Bash and Linux.  However, the arguments I was passing were being formatted in the Windows/DOS style (backslashes for file paths, forward slashes for option flags).

The solution smacked me in the face eventually.  Just run the Node script in PowerShell, and the command line arguments get handled in the Windows style.

I think the rather cryptic comment about npm link may be hinting at a way to run Node from Git Bash, but have it execute in PowerShell, or something like that.  But once I realized I could just run the thing in PowerShell, that worked for me.

To protect myself from repeating my mistake, I added a little check at the beginning of my script:

```js
if(process.env.SHELL) {
  console.error('This script must be run in PowerShell or CMD.  It is not compatible with Bash.');
  process.exit(1);
}
```

There might be a better check to use, but this is what I came up with.